# Prefill checkout values through Javascript (Tealium or AB testing tool)

Tags: checkout

I'm trying to figure out how to prefill some data in the checkout form through Tealium or another JS script injection solution (ex: for AB testing).

I have for example the following field:

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
value: value,
valueUpdate: 'blur',
hasFocus: focused,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
    'aria-required': required,
    'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled,
    maxlength: maxlength
}" name="telephone" placeholder="____/__ __ __" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="G1J60V0" maxlength="13">
```

If I fill it with the following code:

```
document.getElementsByName('telephone')[0].value= whatever_value;
```

I can see the value filled in but the form has not detected a value in the field and when I submitted the form, it highlight this field as if it was empty.

I have tried to simulate a click:

```
document.getElementsByName('telephone')[0].focus();
document.getElementsByName('telephone')[0].select();
document.getElementsByName('telephone')[0].click();
```

but it doesn't help either.

How could I update fields from the checkout with prefilled value and ensure they are taken into account by the usual verifications done on the page?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: Check my answer, Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a module to pre-filled the checkout field like below.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Checkout_Block_Checkout_LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

/**
 * Class LayoutProcessor
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout
 */
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
    * @param array $jsLayout
    * @return array
    */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'John';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['value'] = 'Doe';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['company']['value'] = 'Test Company';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['city']['value'] = 'New Jersy';
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode']['value'] = '123456';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['value'] = '1234567890';


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Then you have to run below commands from the Magento root directory and check.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't use that because I'm looking for a Javascript solution that I could use with javascript injection tools like the ones mentionned in my post. I can inject values with JS without any problem but knockout.js is not taking them into account and I need to be able to make knockout.js understand that new values are available. Thanks!